# White space on top of flash movie within table cell

Tags: html, flash, html-table, whitespace

I have a flash movie, height = 151px width = 228, this is placed within a table cell (
cellpadding = 0 cellspacing = 0 vertical-align = top), but when it displays within the explorer windows there is a white space about 20px above the flash movie. I want the flash movie to appear directly under the grey lines.

Here is a screen shot of the current issue:

[image]

Here is my code for this page:

```
    <table style="width: 900px; vertical-align: top;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 900px; height: 306;" colspan="6" valign="bottom">
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="880" height="306">
                <param name="movie" value="AFM/opening_HKA.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
                <embed src="AFM/opening_HKA.swf" quality="high" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="880" height="306"></embed>
            </object>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 355px; height: 151px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; padding-left: 35px; padding-top: 7px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
            HK America LLC is a leading portfolio investment group. HK America is an active 
            private investment partnership that uses strategies with the goal of generating high
            returns again commercial dwellings.
        </td>
        <td style="width: 80px; height: 151px;"></td>
        <td style="width: 228px; height: 151px; padding: 0 0 0 0; margin: 0 0 0 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; border-top-color: Silver; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid;">
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="228px">
                <param name="movie" value="AFM/button_HKA_Timeline.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <embed src="AFM/button_HKA_Timeline.swf" quality="high" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="228px""></embed>
            </object>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25px; height: 151px;"></td>
        <td style="width: 228px; height: 151px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; border-top-color: Silver; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid;">
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="228">
                <param name="movie" value="AFM/button_HKA_Opportunities.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <embed src="AFM/button_HKA_Opportunities.swf" quality="high" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="228"></embed>
            </object>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 35px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post some of your code so we know exactly what you are doing. Based on your information I could assume that:

- the title is within the table

  - the table containing the titles and the movies has an extra row (or more) between the title and movie which is 20 px tall
- or the title is not in the table

  - that there is a 20 px space between your title and the table

Comment: Your assumption led me to the correct answer. The flash movie height was not set therefore it was causing an issue with the cell padding. I added the height and added a pixel padding of 5 to the top and it worked great. Thank you